# Artifacts using Zero Alpha Shader

Tags: shaders, transparency, artifacts

I am trying to gradually make an object transparent. To this end I mixed in a Principled BSDF with an Alpha of zero.
[image: node setup]

However, this results in the following black artifacts in the picture (shaded image for comparison):
[image: artifacts]
[image: shaded image]

Is this due to some shady normals issue? is there a better way to make objects transparent?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assign a higher value to *Render Properties > Light Paths > Max Bounces > Transparency*

Comment: Hello and welcome, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer, low quality posts may be removed at some point. Could you edit your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works? Perhaps add a few screenshots illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) otherwise it may be converted into a comment.